# Time profiler instruments not showing objective c functions

Tags: objective-c, instruments

I am using instruments but i see only 0x00345 etc in time profiler i do not see any objective c code although i am enabling the 'show objective c only' option...any help appreciated![image: Without the Show objective c only option]

[image: With the Show objective c only option]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most likely cause of your problem is that debug symbols are not being generated for your project. Without debug symbols Instruments just shows memory addresses, like the ones shown in your first screenshot.

There are two ways to fix the problem. First, profile your app with the Debug build configuration. Use the Scheme menu in the project window toolbar to change the build configuration. Second, set the Generate Debug Symbols build setting to Yes for the Release build configuration.